# How can I rotate my top face without it affecting the other faces direction?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to rotate my top face while keeping the geometry as it is.
As you can see in the picture below, when I rotate it also adjust other faces. I want to keep all the other faces in a vertical direction - not also rotating/scaling inwards.

How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the vertical edges vertical, you probably don't want to rotate it; you probably want to shear it:

[image]

Select the shear tool.  Select your face.  From my view, click near one of the vertical sides of the box displayed for the shear and drag.